# Yaml file parsing iterating values

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, yaml, pyyaml

I have a yaml file with the following structure:

```
User1:
  email: test@test.com
  firstname: test
  lastname: user
  id: AZTEST123
  role: manager
  team: test
```

I want to be able to iterate over this yaml file and use the values in a script I am writing below:

```
def get_users(yaml_file="test.yml"):
  with open(yaml_file, 'r') as stream:
    try:
      data = yaml.load(stream)
      print(data)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
      print(exc)
  return data

def create_user(users):
  for user in users:
    print(user[1])
    try:
      print(user['email'])
      url = 'https://api.test.com/users'
      payload = {
          'user': {
              'type': 'user',
              'name': user['firstname'] + ' ' + user['lastname'],
              'email': user['email'],
              'role': user['role']
          }
      }
      r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
      print ('Status Code: {code}').format(code=r.status_code)
      print (r.json())
      sc.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel="#test",
        text="User {user} has been added to Test :tada:".format(user=user['firstname']),
        user="test")
    except requests.ConnectionError as error_message:
      print (error_message)

users = get_users()

create_user(users)
```

When I print the received `print(data)` from my code it returns:

```
{'User1': {'email': 'test@test.com', 'firstname': 'test', 'lastname': 'user', 'id': 'AZTEST123', 'role': 'manager', 'team': 'test'}}
```

But when I try to use the values: `user['firstname']` I get an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And when I `print(user[0])` it returns:

```
U
```

What am I missing here, how can I iterate through these items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop, loops over a dictionary, returning the keys. So `user` will have the value `User1`.

What you want to do is:

```
for username in users:
    user = users[username]
    print(user['firstname'])
```